# 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror, dtype

```
    my_stor = np.zeros(27)
    for i in range(0,27):
      if net.storage.bus[i] == self.bus and net.storage.in_service[i] == True :
        my_stor[i] = net.storage.index[i]
        avail[my_stor[i],time] = 1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\SreeRam\Desktop\Thesis\Main_cooopy.py", line 339, in <module>
    run_timeseries(net, time_steps=range(0, 60))

  File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandapower\timeseries\run_time_series.py", line 331, in run_timeseries
    run_loop(net, ts_variables, **kwargs)

  File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandapower\timeseries\run_time_series.py", line 303, in run_loop
    run_time_step(net, time_step, ts_variables, **kwargs)

  File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandapower\timeseries\run_time_series.py", line 101, in run_time_step
    ctrl.time_step(time_step)

  File "C:\Users\SreeRam\Desktop\Thesis\Main_cooopy.py", line 194, in time_step
    my_stor[i] = net.storage.index[i]

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment
```

In the code above, I wanted to store the values in `my_stor[i]` for every i when the condition is true. But I am getting the above error. I also tried replacing `np.zeros` by `np.ones` and `np.array`. Still the same error. Is it anything to do with `dtype`?

Comment: What line does the Exception says it happening?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: `my_stor[i] = net.storage.index[i]` this line and the error is for `my_stor[i]`

Comment: `a = np.zeros(27); a[4] = 34` works. What is `net.storage.index`?

Comment: What is the value of `net.storage.index[i]`? What is its type?

Comment: @wwii it is just the index of an array

Comment: `type(net.storage.index)
Out[34]: pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index`

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like a primitive value to me. I'm not sure numpy knows how to handle this type.

Comment: the values of `net.storage.index` ranges from 0-27

Comment: Also make sure `my_stor` wasn't overwritten with a scalar float in your real code.

Comment: Yes, but this type probably has a string representation that looks like a number. The numpy array is expecting a Python primitive value, like a `int` or `float`. You first need to convert this index type.

Comment: `a = np.zeros(27); a[7] = df.index[5]` also works when `type(df.index) --> <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>`. ... [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite

Comment: @boechat107 I also tried `int(net.storage.index`. Still the same.

Comment: Try `print(type(my_stor))` instead...

Comment: `type(my_stor)
Out[36]: numpy.ndarray`

Comment: `pdb` might be useful for inspection. @rocky, does `int(net.storage.index[i])` cause exactly the same error?

Comment: OK, so your problem is officially not reproducible. Until you give us a self-contained block of code that when run reproduces your problem we won't be able to help.

Comment: I hope you printed `type(my_stor)` right before the error happens, and not somewhere else in your code...

Comment: @AndrasDeak  `<class 'numpy.int64'>` this is the type for `my_stor` before the error.

Comment: There's your problem ;) Somewhere before the error you overwrote the `ndarray` `my_stor` with a single numpy integer by the same name.

Comment: @boechat107 Yes. It gives the exact same error